# running functions one after other in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

after `setState`, i want to call `service.logout()`, then `Auth.logout()` function,

```
 componentWillMount() {
    if (!(this.Auth.loggedIn())){
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    } else {
      this.setState({token : this.Auth.getToken()}).then(service.logout(this.state.token)).then( this.Auth.logout())
      // console.log('token',this.state.token)

    }
  }
```

but im getting `error` like this,

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
Logout.componentWillMount
src/components/auth/Logout.js:20
  17 | if (!(this.Auth.loggedIn())){
  18 |   this.props.history.replace('/login');
  19 | } else {
> 20 |   this.setState({token : this.Auth.getToken()}).then(service.logout(this.state.token)).then( this.Auth.logout())
  21 |   // console.log('token',this.state.token)
  22 |  
  23 | }
```

Comment: What is this.Auth ? Have you imported the same in your file ? Could you please share you code.

Comment: @rohankangale `import AuthService from './AuthService'`, in then construcor i have added this line,  `this.Auth = new AuthService();`

Comment: I will suggest you to move this code to componentDidMount(), instead of componentWillMount(). Also, do check whether you are getting the response for this.Auth.loggedIn().

Comment: @rohankangale` this.Auth.loggedIn()` works as, if token not present it redirects url to `/login`

Comment: Ok. If your service function is working fine, then move your code to componentDidMount().

Comment: @rohankangale yes, now im working with componentDidMount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.setState does not return "Promise" and that's why it is not proper to use "then" method to chain the operations. [ref.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

If your "service.logout(..)" returns Promise than probably following one will work.

```
componentWillMount() {
if (!(this.Auth.loggedIn())){
  this.props.history.replace('/login');
} else {
  const authToken = this.Auth.getToken();
  this.setState({token : authToken }, () => { 
       service.logout(authToken).then( this.Auth.logout());
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

from `https://reactjs.org/docs/`

[image]

so i think this would solve your problem

```js
      this.setState({token : this.Auth.getToken()} , async () => {
       await service.logout(this.state.token) 
       await this.Auth.logout()
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. First of all, don't use componentWillMount instead use
>      **componentDidMount**. componentWillMount is going to **deprecate in
>      react17**.
> 2. setState don't return a promise, rather you can use a callback which
>      will execute after state has been set.
> 3. In below example I call logout function in call back which returns a
>      promise. There you can use .then() because that function returns a
>      promise with help of ***async await***
> 4. You can also direct make callback function to a async callback function using **async** syntax.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (false){
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    } else {
      this.setState({token : 'one'}, () => {
        this.logout(this.state.token).then(() => {
          // Do whatever you want
          console.log('three');
        });
      });
    }
  }

 logout = async (token) => {
     const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => { console.log('two'); return resolve("done!"); }, 1000)
     });

     return await a;
  }
```

To check the working example [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mhgj5f)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't know react, but I know Angular.
If the service.logout() returns an Observable, then shouldn't you bind `.then()` method with it return value, like this?

```
this.setState({token : this.Auth.getToken()}).then(service.logout(this.state.token).then( this.Auth.logout()))
```

Comment: What is the return value type of the service.logout() ?

Comment: `service.logout()` will do API call and empty the token in db, but now that call is not working

Comment: I am not asking about the implementation, but about the return type. And if your call fails - then you should investigate the problem. If that is on your side (request problem) or if it on API problem (service side)